# How to use ROWNUM for a maximum and another minimum ordering in ORACLE?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Currently i am trying to output the top row for 2 condition. One is max and one is min.
Current code

```
Select * 
from  (MY SELECT STATEMENT order by A desc) 
where ROWNUM <= 1
```

**UPDATE**
I am now able to do for both condition. But i need the A to be the highest, if same then check for the B lowest.

E.g Lets say there is 2 rows, Both A is 100 and B is 50 for one and 60 for other.
In this case the 100:50 shld be choose because A is same then B is lowest.

E.g
Lets say there is 2 rows, A is 100 for one and 90 for other, since one is higher no need to check for B.

I tried using max and min but this method seems to work better, any suggestions

Comment: You have changed the context of this question a lot, you should ADD to the question not replace it, in my opinion

Comment: Please explain (using an example) of what you now mean for A "to be highest" (highest of what?) (compared to what?) and "if same" (same as what?)

Comment: I am with Used_By_Already here, I don't understand the question. Adding to the questions stated: Shall the query return one record or two or is it sometimes one, sometimes two, depending on some condition?

Comment: i updated. it shld always return one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, after your clarification, you are looking for one record. With Max A. And the smallest B, in case there is more than one record with MAX A. This is simply:

```
Select * 
from  (MY SELECT STATEMENT order by A desc, B) 
where ROWNUM = 1;
```

This sorts by A descending first, so you get all maximal A records first. Then it sorts by B, so inside each A group you get the least B first. This gives you the desired A record first, no matter if the found A is unique or not.

Answer (score 1):

or avoid the vagaries of rownun and go for row_number() instead:

```
SELECT
      *
FROM (
            SELECT
                  *
                , ROW_NUMBER (ORDER BY A DESC) adesc
                , ROW_NUMBER (ORDER BY B ASC)  basc
            FROM SomeQuery
      ) 
WHERE adesc = 1
      OR basc = 1
```

---

footnote: `select *` is a convenience only, please replace with the actual columns required along with table names etc.

Comment: You can't use `*` and `row_number()` in the same select list, I think?

Comment: That is 100% true, it is used here simply to denote "I do not know what columns you need - please provide that detail".

Comment: when i try the above method, adesc = 1 causes my output for adesc value  also to be 1. Why does this happen?

Comment: Because there now is a column called adesc (and one called basc) which didn't exist before. You can exclude these from the select clause of the outer query.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM
    (Select foo.*, 0 as union_order
    from  (MY SELECT STATEMENT order by A desc) foo
    where ROWNUM <= 1
    UNION
    Select foo.*, 1
    from  (MY SELECT STATEMENT order by B asc) foo
    where ROWNUM <= 1)
ORDER BY
    union_order
```

Comment: The result of a union is an unordered set.  Oracle is free to return the second part of the union first (and might do so if it executes both parts concurrently.)

Comment: Right, but now you're using both `*` and a literal, which is not allowed.  See fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4d371/2

Comment: Again, you're right. I haven't used Oracle in 3 or 4 years, and this does work in SQL Server. I assumed it would in Oracle too.

Answer (score 0):

Try this if that works

```
Select * 
from  (MY SELECT STATEMENT order by A desc) 
where ROWNUM <= 1
union
Select * 
from  (MY SELECT STATEMENT order by A asc) 
where ROWNUM <= 1
```

Comment: The result of a union is an unordered set. Oracle is free to return the second part of the union first (and might do so if it executes both parts concurrently.)